# Ignoring implemented methods from an interface?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have an input processor interface that listens on the screen and gives feedback to a button class, I have no control over the methods created in the interface. Now I'm trying to write a button class so that I can declare it within the class and call touchUp and touchDown only so I've not got code pollution.

Here's what I'm trying to cut down:

```
Button button = new Button();
        button.setInputListener(new InputProcessor() {
            @Override
            public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        );
```

Within the button class I have the following code:

```
public void setInputListener(InputProcessor inputProcessor){
    this.inputProcessor = inputProcessor;
}
```

Comment: you can override all the methods return false if you are not handling and true if you are handling.

Comment: Yes I know but I'm trying to avoid having them in code in the first place.

Comment: Then don't put them in the interface. Or don't use an interface (make it a class instead, with non-abstract methods, so they don't need to be overridden)

Comment: Interfaces are created for that purpose. Well there is always a work-around , you can create one custom class that implement the interface and provide some default implementation for each method. later you can extend that class instead of using interface.

Comment: Just use `InputAdapter` then. It allready returns false for all methods in the interface and you only need to override the ones you need. The disadvantage is, that it is a class and you cannot extend other classes, if you use the `Adapter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out for anybody else that's stuck on it. You've got to create another class that implements that interface and make sure it's abstract, here's an example:

```
public abstract class ButtonListener implements InputProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can do this anywhere,

```
Button button = new Button();
        button.setInputListener(new ButtonListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
                    return super.keyDown(keycode);
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: It's called an Adapter. LibGDX already provides one of these: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputAdapter.html